# Who are the 7 Heroines of Bonyari High?

Tags: nisekoi

I have come across this term and I wonder who exactly the 7 heroines are?

They are mentioned here in chapter 132:

[image: Seven Heroines mentioned in Manga]

And here:

[image: One of the Seven Heroines]

Can someone give me a list of them?

I know of Chitoge, Kosaki and Marika. Haru seems not to be one of them.

Comment: I didn't actually get, what do you mean by 7 heroines

Comment: [Some dude on chiebukuro](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q13132880368) finds himself similarly confused, and posits that, at the least, Chitoge, Kosaki, Marika, and Tsugumi count among their number, plus possibly Kyoko (the teacher). [A different dude on chiebukuro](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q10132389900) adds Ruri, Raku, and Shuu to that list. Note that the word that is translated as "heroine" is 英雄, which is gender-nonspecific in Japanese. (Not that Shuu wouldn't make a splendid heroine.)

Comment: I've added pictures from the manga to help clarify the question;however, I'm not sure if all translations use this phrasing of 7 heroines here.

Comment: @senshin thats a good point, do you think the translator knew they were all girls and translated it that way oder did he possibly make a mistake? And thnaks for adding the pictures

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The seven hero(ine)s of Bonyari (凡矢理高校七英雄, bonyari koukou nana eiyuu) were confirmed in a **Nisekoi official Fanbook** released in August 2015 (ニセコイ　ファンブック　トクレポ). The fan translation by Red Hawks being released more than one year before, the team probably assumed at the time that the seven people in question were girls without any solid proof (but they are seemingly right nonetheless).

---

**Sources:**

The actual list of the seven heroines is mentioned on [this japanese blog](http://ameblo.jp/tuyo9624/entry-12061250189.html), apparently specializing in Nisekoi trivia. The list is given additional credence by [this other blog](http://sclpsn.blog.fc2.com/blog-entry-1082.html), which reviews the fanbook extensively and mentions, without expliciting all names though, that 5 of the 7 heroines fell in love with Raku, and that the other 2 didn't appear yet as of the writing of the review. The same list appears on the japanese [wikipedia page of Nisekoi](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%8B%E3%82%BB%E3%82%B3%E3%82%A4#cite_note-60) as an annotation to the seven heroines entry of the glossary section, and a number of other pages of people who asked the same question.

---

**Trivia:**

The seven heroines of Bonyari refer to 7 people of Bonyari High, who possess a unique talent or incredible popularity among other students of Bonyari. Even though she's not a part of it, Haru is mentioned to be a likely candidate for a "future" list of these seven heroines.
The seven heroines of Bonyari seem to be a cute variation of the "7 wonders of school" (学校の七不思議, gakkou no nana fushigi) in Japanese scary urban legends, which is also a relatively common trope in manga.

---

**Onto the actual list:**

- The golden rose princess [golden rose], **Chitoge Kirisaki** (黄金の薔薇姫（ゴールデン・ローズ）)
- The lovely lily missy [pretty lily], **Kosaki Onodera** (可憐なる百合嬢（プリティ・リリィ）)
- The noble mountain arrowhead [noble amaryllis], **Seishirou Tsugumi** (気高き山慈姑（ノーブル・アマリリス）)
- The beloved marigold [lovely gold], **Marika Tachibana** (愛の千寿菊（ラブリー・ゴールド）)
- The gracious sunrise orchid [grace cattleya], **Yui Kanakura** (優美なる日出蘭（グレース・カトレア）)
- The melody camellia princess [melody camellia], **Roxanne Kyouko Gotou**  (旋律の椿姫（メロディー・カメリア）)
- The innocent turnip girl [innocent turnip], **Hikari Saegusa** (無邪気な菘娘（イノセント・ターナップ）)

Notes: arrowhead refers to the [flower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sagittaria_sagittifolia), not an actual arrowhead. Also, brackets denote names written phonetically in english in the original japanese text.

---

Note that, like the japanese review of the fanbook mentions, Yui was not introduced nor a teacher in Bonyari yet when the seven heroines were mentioned in chapter 132. It can be speculated that someone else occupied her place in the listing at the time, but it is not known who.

As for Roxanne Kyouko Gotou (後藤・ロクサーヌ・響子) and Hikari Saegusa (七草光), they were mentioned by name and both didn't appear yet in any work as of this writing. (Also note that the pronunciation of their names may actually be different than what I wrote. I'm fairly confident about their first names, but their family names, especially, may have a different spelling; I chose to write Gotou and Saegusa because they are common pronunciation for these.)